# Loop when trying to update ubuntu using apt-get

Tags: apt, upgrade

So I have gotten stuck while trying to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.

When running the update command I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-36 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up whoopsie (0.2.52.5) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service thermald at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop at service smfpd if started
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and mountkernfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package whoopsie (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.7) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service thermald at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop at service smfpd if started
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and mountkernfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 whoopsie
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I gather from the log is there is some kind of loop in the process possibly a boot order but I have no idea how to remove the problem so that the update can take place.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This `smfpd` does not seem to be from [the official repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=smfpd). What is it?

Comment: smfpd = samsung print driver.

Comment: I solved with: mv /etc/init.d/smfpd /etc/init.d/smfpd.old